# Valid content-type for XML, HTML and XHTML documents

Tags: html, xml, http, xhtml, web-standards

What are the correct content-types for XML, HTML and XHTML documents?

I need to write a simple crawler that only fetches these kinds of files.

Nowadays http://example.net/index.html can serve for example a JPEG file due to mod_rewrite, so I need to check the content-type from response header and compare it with a list of allowed content-types.

Where can I get such a list from?

Comment: About fragments see http://stackoverflow.com/q/19303361/287948  and https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-fragment

Answer (score 295, accepted):

HTML: `text/html`, full-stop.

XHTML: `application/xhtml+xml`, or only if following HTML compatbility guidelines, `text/html`. See the W3 [Media Types Note](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/).

XML: `text/xml`, `application/xml` ([RFC 2376](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2376.txt)).

There are also many other media types based around XML, for example `application/rss+xml` or `image/svg+xml`. It's a safe bet that any unrecognised but registered ending in `+xml` is XML-based. See the [IANA list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/) for registered media types ending in `+xml`.

(For unregistered `x-` types, all bets are off, but you'd hope `+xml` would be respected.)

Comment: On differences between `text/xml` and `application/xml` see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832357/whats-the-difference-between-text-xml-vs-application-xml-for-webservice-respons

Comment: The same is valid for *fragments*, see http://w3.org/TR/xml-fragment or [this other qustion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19303361/287948).