# Download an XML file using a REST api

Tags: java, xml, rest

I need to write a `REST` api which would send an `XML` file as response.
I am confused with what `MediaType` should be defined as the response.

```
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
```

or

```
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
```

The API will be served from a GET request and I want the file to be downloaded in the client side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Valid content-type for XML, HTML and XHTML documents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965587/valid-content-type-for-xml-html-and-xhtml-documents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will go with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)`, as the `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)` is a constant for `application/octet-stream` which is usually used for binary type (such as video, music and stuff)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest dont send file directly.
read file at server end and send the file content as a response.

so it will look like

```
@GET
@Produce("application/xml")
    public Response sendData(){
      //code to read file and store in a string object

     return Response.built.ok(string object);
    }
```