# Content type beside text/html

Tags: html, mime-types, meta-tags

You probably all know the tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

I was wondering what values are there beside `text/html` for the `content` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common ones include:

- text/xml
- application/json
- image/jpeg

Comprehensive list here :
http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html#mime-types-list

Comment: But it’s not really possible to use a `meta` element in JSON or JPEG.

Answer (score 2):

The only content type values you'd want to use for HTML are `text/html` and `application/xhtml+xml` for XHTML.

See also:  [Valid content-type for XML, HTML and XHTML documents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2965587/362536)

Answer (score 0):

This is the long winded HTML4 way of writing the meta tag. In HTML5 it's much simpler.

New:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Since you can technically pass just about any form of data to the web browser the

```
content="text/html
```

Was meant to tell the browser that is was going to be displaying text/html.

Meta tags are used to describe data about the web page. The data is not displayed, however it can be used for several things. Example supplying and author, giving a description, keywords, and even a document refresh interval.

[HTML meta tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)

Also....

[Using Meta Tags in HTML: Some Basics and Best Practices](https://www.sitepoint.com/meta-tags-html-basics-best-practices/)