# Send HTTP.post() with XML?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, http, ionic-framework

Is there any way to use `HTTP.post(url, body, headers)` of ionic-native with a XML body?

[post()](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/#post) there it says it needs an object (JSON) but my webservice needs an XML request.

Is there maybe something like an xml object?

Comment: You can specify Accept and Content-type header property and set to application/xml. Check this already answered question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965587/valid-content-type-for-xml-html-and-xhtml-documents

Comment: It says it needs an object. It does not say it needs JSON. If it needed JSON then it would expect a string.

Comment: thanks, ill try to change to content type!

Comment: as i tried a string, it said it really need json object

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set *content-type* to *text/xml* like in the following example?

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

Comment: The question is not about the `XMLHttpRequest` object

Comment: I am sorry. If you want wo use the http client you only need to set content-type to text/xml

Comment: Really? So why did the OP say they got an error when they tried to pass a string of XML as the body?

Comment: I will try this as soon as possible