# How to create a scheduler to export the APi result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, scheduled-tasks

I have an API which gives a list of details, i would like to export the result of this API in to xml format and this export functionality should run once in a day. There is no UI to export this functionality. Its a kind of backend task which will run on a particular time every day.

I am using C# and Asp.net Core. Can some one suggest me to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems to solve.

1. Scheduling - you will need a dedicated service to execute the service. This can be done in azure timer triggers
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp
2. Creating an XML file - On your server, once you fetch the xml contents, you will need to write the file to the response. You need to set the response content type
   [Valid content-type for XML, HTML and XHTML documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965587/valid-content-type-for-xml-html-and-xhtml-documents)
   You will also need to write the contents of the xml file to the output
   [C# Asp.net write file to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072814/c-sharp-asp-net-write-file-to-client)